# Unproportional Bubble Chart with the size paramater

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, charts, bubble-chart

I´ve created a bubble chart and I put in some testing values as follow:

```
    this.chart1.Series["blueBubble"].Points.AddXY(2, 3, 6);
    this.chart1.Series["redBubble"].Points.AddXY(1, 0, 7);
    this.chart1.Series["yellowBubble"].Points.AddXY(1, 3, 8);
```

As I put in the size of the particular bubble to the third parameter of AddXY function, the sizing is done in a completely wrong proportional representation. See picture:

[image]

How can I change the bubble sizes to the right proposition representation?

Comment: Could you give a little more information as to what framework you are using to create the bubble chart? Are you using the WinForms bubblechar (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456658.aspx)?

Comment: @JStromwick sorry, yes I am using that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks really weird.

The best explanation I have is that the sizes always start with the smallest one set and scale them going from 1 to the largest one set in proprtional steps.

Sounds awfully strange? Yup.

Here are the notes on MSDN on [BubbleScaleMax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489209.aspx) and [BubbleScaleMin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456758.aspx)

> If set to Auto, the smallest plotted bubble is displayed using the
>   minimum size.
>
> If set to Auto, the largest plotted bubble will be displayed using the
>   maximum size.

Setting these properties to anything else but `Auto` is tricky; you could use this:

```
 chart1.Series[0]["BubbleScaleMin"] = "0";
```

Or any number **smaller** than **your** smallest size.

Or, if you prefer, here is a workaround: Add a transparent dummy point with size = 0 and suitable x- and y-values:

```
int i = this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 1, 0);
this.chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = Color.Transparent;
```

Before and after:

[image][image]