# Is there a way to convert bubble chart size?

Tags: vb.net, charts, mschart, fusioncharts, bubble-chart

I have created a bubble chart using the fusion charts api in asp.net. The question/issue I have is leaning more on scaling the chart itself, rather than the particular library I used to generate it.

The chart I have is designed like this:

- X = roi
- y = lift
- circle size = revenue

The code below sets the max/min values of the x axis:

```
    roiMax += 30 'pad the max and min roi values so the bubble wont cut off
    roiMin -= 30
```

I used the new roi min/max values and set them as the minimum/maximum x axis values. It seems to work in most cases. However, if the points displayed are all near each other, then the bubbles become squished together.

If I comment out the portion where I set the x/y max min value of the chart, it looks to scale more properly. However, there are bubbles that cut off if it reaches the edge of the chart. So I want to try to set min/max values for x and y so I can show the full bubble. However, to do that I need to use the circle size to grab the length so I can determine the proper chart limits.  Is there a way to convert the size into units of x or the units of y for me to find the proper limit?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - You tag chart but also vb and fusion charts but not mschart. What do you really use??

Comment: @TaW - I updated my question above. I use the fusion charts library in asp.net. The question I have is gearing towards more on chart scaling, rather than the api that I used it on, so I thought that the tags I chose were more relevant.

Comment: You are asking about technical details which are closely related to the control/api you are usinig. The fusion charts library in asp.net is not the same as MSChart afaik, so one needs to know which it is.. I know a bit about [bubble scaling in MSChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556748/unproportional-bubble-chart-with-the-size-paramater/33557399?s=1|2.6547#33557399) but have no idea how the rules in fusion charts go..